# How to move Google Cloud DNS entries between 2 projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I want to do something really simple, but it looks like it's almost impossible to do.

I have different Projects inside my Google Cloud DNS account.

I want to move (migrate?) some of the entries (domains) from one project to another. I don't want to go the delete / recreate path since all domains are live and I don't want any downtime. It also looks like this process creates new NS entries that need changes at the registrar ...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is possible. Let's assume **project-a** is the project you want to migrate from and **project-b** is where you want to migrate to.

Export your record sets:

> gcloud dns record-sets export $FILENAME --zone $YOUR_ZONE --project project-a

Create a managed zone in **project-b**

> gcloud dns managed-zones create $NAME --dns-name=your.com. --description $DESC --project project-b

Import the record sets.
Before you do this you will need to remove to standard records (maybe someone knows how to do this better).

Edit the $FILENAME that was created above when you exported the record-sets and remove two items that look exactly like the following:

```
---
kind: dns#resourceRecordSet
name: clevar.cloud.
rrdatas:
- ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.
ttl: 21600
type: NS
---
kind: dns#resourceRecordSet
name: clevar.cloud.
rrdatas:
- ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 14 21600 3600 259200
  300
ttl: 21600
type: SOA
```

After you've saved the file import it to your new managed zone in **project-b**

> gcloud dns record-sets import $FILENAME --zone $YOUR_ZONE --project project-b

Finally, when you are looking at the managed zone in the Cloud Console (e.g. https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones/$YOUR_ZONE/details?project=project-b) you'll see text in the upper right next to your login that says "REGISTRAR SETUP"

Click that and make sure that your domain nameserver records match what is in that box.

When I went through this the two projects had different nameservers so I did not have to worry about conflicts from the two projects trying to manage my DNS. If they are the same you can disable the DNS API on **project-a** without losing any data.

After you confirmed you have all your record sets in project-b and you've set the NS records properly with your domain registrar you should create a test record and use that as a way to confirm that everything is working / has propagated.

**Note: I ran through the above and I had my zone moved over within an hour propagation and all, however, you may not be as lucky so give it some time before you assume it isn't working.

Comment: An important note the default nameservers might be different between your two zones. For example in my first project the default was ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com but the in second project it was ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com so I ended up having to change that with my registrar.

Answer (score 1):

In order to import the zone with `gcloud dns record-sets import ...`, the main SOA and NS should be removed from the exported output.
I'm using the `awk` command to remove the SOA and NS records. note that it will remove all of the `NS` records, including custom ones you may need

```bash
gcloud dns record-sets export /dev/stdout --zone "${ZONE}" --project "${SOURCE_PROJECT}" | awk -v RS='---\n' '!/type: (SOA|NS)/ && NF { print RS $0 }' > "${FILENAME}" 
gcloud dns record-sets import  "${FILENAME}" --zone "${ZONE}" --project "${DESTINATION_PROJECT}" --delete-all-existing
```

Comment: I followed these commands exactly but it is important to note the NS record might not be the same between your two projects in gcloud.